# Union static dataframe vs spark structured streaming dataframe in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Is there any alternative way to apply the union between static dataframe and structured streaming dataframe in PySpark?

Comment: Alternative to what? Using .withWatermark ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible standardly.

Using `foreachBatch()` with batch function will cater for this, though.

See https://docs.databricks.com/en/structured-streaming/foreach.html

Comment: If you have any solution could you please share the solution

Comment: You show no code and the static df cannot be refreshed

Comment: Is there any possibility to return that dataframe as output and we can use later

Comment: I don’t want to write the data to disk instead I want to return dataframe back

Comment: Not possible. You need to do this way as far as I know. Used for Sinks.